# Penetration testing Why does this not work - SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, code-injection

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $genre WHERE title LIKE '%%$search%%' OR info LIKE '%%$search%%' OR type LIKE '%%$search%%' OR Name LIKE '%%$search%%' OR locate LIKE '%%$search%%' OR phone LIKE '%%$search%%' OR price LIKE '%%$search%%' OR postcode LIKE '%%$search%%' ";
```

THE CODE ABOVE
THE INJECTION BELOW

```
food' UNION (SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, 9 FROM 
information_schema.tables);--
```

I have a database named Classifieds , i have only recently learned of the fatal mistakes i am making when it comes to injection hacks so i am going through my code s to do what i can to make the necessery changes ect... I have been watching videos online and doing some research and i have managed to hack my database very easy as you can see from the code, it is very unprotected. But i came across the following injection and i cannot get it to work... Can anybody see why this will not work... Thank you

these are the rows i have in each table. i have around 40 tables , all genre related. ie, computers, mobile phones, electronics, clothes ect ect....

```
$vid = $row['id']; 
$type = $row['type'];
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['Name'];
$image = $row['img']; 
$info = $row['info'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
$title = $row['title'];
$locate = $row['locate'];
$postcode = $row['postcode'];
$price = $row['price'];
$videos = $row['videos'];
```

Comment: ALSO how would i better protect my database from sql injection and any other hacks.. Thank you for any info.

Comment: the select in your union must contain the same variables as the first select

Comment: so Select * FROM FROM $genre WHERE title - being 3.

Comment: or SELECT * FROM $genre WHERE title LIKE '%%$search%%' OR info LIKE '%%$search%%' OR type LIKE '%%$search%%' OR Name LIKE '%%$search%%' OR locate LIKE '%%$search%%' OR phone LIKE '%%$search%%' OR price LIKE '%%$search%%' OR postcode LIKE '%%$search%%'  being 10... iv tried all numbers up 14

Comment: food' UNION (SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, (((iv tried 0 - 14))) FROM 
information_schema.tables);--

Comment: OR is it ....food' UNION (SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, $genre, title, name, ect ect FROM 
information_schema.tables);--